# Why Nutch dosen't Index into Elasticsearch a no English language sites?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, indexing, nutch, persian

I am trying to make a Search Engine, for this, I'm using `Nutch 2.x`, `Elasticsearch 1.4.4`, `MongoDB 3.5` and everything was OK, when I tried to crawl a site (URL [1](http://www.isna.ir/news/96050603469/%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%BA%DB%8C%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AA%D8%A6%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%B4%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%85)) with Persian text (not English) it done everything (means crawl to index) but the index did not work and Elasticsearch did not show the page that crawled. I tested it with another site with Persian text URL [2](http://snn.ir/fa/news/623720/%D9%86%D8%AA%DB%8C%D8%AC%D9%87-%DA%A9%D9%86%DA%A9%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%B1%DB%8C-%DB%B1%DB%B5-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%85%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%AF) and it works correctly and index also is OK.

[1](http://www.isna.ir/news/96050603469/%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%BA%DB%8C%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AA%D8%A6%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%B4%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%85): [The First URL - Did not work!](http://www.isna.ir/news/96050603469/%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%BA%DB%8C%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AA%D8%A6%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%B4%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%85)

[2](http://snn.ir/fa/news/623720/%D9%86%D8%AA%DB%8C%D8%AC%D9%87-%DA%A9%D9%86%DA%A9%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%B1%DB%8C-%DB%B1%DB%B5-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%85%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%AF): [The Second URL - It worked](http://snn.ir/fa/news/623720/%D9%86%D8%AA%DB%8C%D8%AC%D9%87-%DA%A9%D9%86%DA%A9%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%B1%DB%8C-%DB%B1%DB%B5-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%85%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%AF)

Why did the first URL not index? What the reason of this happening? Is it from the site (?) and if from it what causes it?

Comment: Can you share the error message/log regarding the failing URL? did the URL got fetched/parsed?

Comment: @JorgeLuis How to I can find the message or log? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: You could check the `logs/hadoop.log` to see if there is any reference to the URL, my guess is that is being rejected by some URL filter, you could use the command `bin/nutch org.apache.nutch.net.URLFilterChecker -allCombined` and paste your URL to see if is being accepted or rejected.